# Creating a dropdown in Google sheets via an API call

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client

I'm trying to create a dropdown menu in Google sheets using the PHP API, but not having an luck and unable to source any examples

There is an accepted answer at [How to set validation method in Google spreadsheets API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47079970/how-to-set-validation-method-in-google-spreadsheets-api?answertab=active#tab-top)

but it fails at the final command

> $result = $service->spreadsheets->batchUpdate($fileId, $bodyReq);

with:

```
     "error": {
        "code": 400,
        "message": "Invalid value at 'requests.set_data_validation.range.sheet_id' (TYPE_INT32), 
\"1sEoQb5TVYSWHByiDNWGF6B....\""
```

If anyone has a working example it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think that providing the value of `$bodyReq` will help users think of your issue and the solution.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone finding this later, the confusion is that

```
$range->setSheetId(YOUR_SHEET_ID); //replace this by your sheet ID
```

is expecting an integer relating to the ID of the actual sheet, not the Spreadsheet ID - in this case 0.

[How to find the Sheet ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ED149.png)

Comment: I'm glad you found the solution. Please remember [accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Thank you.